# How to get data from the configMap that mounted as volume in Golang

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, containers, configmap

I have a JSON file mounted by configMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config.json: |
    {{- toPrettyJson $.Values.serviceConfig | nindent 4 }}

kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: service-config
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
```

In deployment.yaml, it's:

```
    spec:
      ... ...
      volumes:
        - name: config-vol
          configMap:
            name: service-config
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          ... ...
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /src/config
              name: config-vol
```

My application needs to get that JSON file and use it, but how to retreive it by Go code. I searched it on the Internet but found nothing. If it's not able to retrieve, how can we use it? It's my first time touching the configMap, and I'm sorry if it's a dumb question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just open `/src/config/config.json` like any other file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `deployment.yaml` is pointing to the wrong configmap name first.

you can use something like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: command
data:
  command.json: |
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "running sh script on node..!"
---
          - name: command
            image: IMAGE
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            volumeMounts:
            - name: commandfile
              mountPath: /test/command.json <---------------Path where you want to mount or add it and used by application from there as it is
              subPath: command.json
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: commandfile
            configMap:
              name: command       <------------------ configmap name should match
```

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. I forgot to change the name before I paste it on the question summary. Besides this, how can I retrieve the data?

Comment: This is only way you can mount it as env variable, or use init container set it properly as per your requirement to main container.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I mount it as env variable? I tried using envFrom in deployment.yaml but I don't know how to get it from the code

Comment: are you using which lanugae ? you can check simply by checking environment, it will get set as environment variable, if python it will  `os.env("NAME OF VAR")`

Comment: check this out : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables