# How to set the value in envFrom as the value of env?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a configMap that stores a json file:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config.json: |
    {{- toPrettyJson $.Values.serviceConfig | nindent 4 }}

kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: service-config
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
```

In my deployment.yaml, I use `volume` and `envFrom`

```
    spec:
      ... ...
      volumes:
        - name: config-vol
          configMap:
            name: service-config
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: service-config
          ... ...
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /src/config
              name: config-vol
```

After I deployed the helm and run `kubectl describe pods`, I god this:

```
    Environment Variables from:
      service-config  ConfigMap  Optional: false
```

I wonder how can I get/use this `service-config` in my code? My `values.yaml` can extract the value under `env` but I don't know how to extract the value of configMap. Is there a way I can move this service-config or the json file stored in it as the variable of `env` in values.yaml? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question: the way you use this `service-config` in your code would be to reference the environment variables that the `envFrom` section is injecting into your container. If you want to read `config.json` as a file instead, you could mount it as a volume.

Comment: I have mounted it as a volume, I still don't know how to read the config.json as a file. Do you know how? I can't find a code example. I also asked it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72485108/how-to-get-data-from-the-configmap-that-mounted-as-volume-in-golang/72486045?noredirect=1#comment128060852_72486045

Comment: With this setup you should have a file `/src/config/config.json` that you can read normally.  You could also update the `env:` block to put the JSON text into an environment variable, but I wouldn't typically do both.